How to draw a bilinear gradient along a selection/line in GIMP (as though indented by a cylinder or round object)?
In GIMP, I'm trying to make an "indentation" effect/image that I will later use in another program (Blender) as a stencil.
I have a selection in GIMP, in the shape of the outline of a round-cornered square.
I want to fill the selection with what I think should be a bilinear (and adjustable) gradient (white to some form of grey/black), with the "center point" of the bilinear gradient being along center of the path of the line.
How can this be done?

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. If you mean you want the gradient to follow around the outline, AFAIK it's not possible.  However it can be done in Inkscape. It's not obvious though. There's a youtube tutorial here demonstrating the basic technique. The gradient is fully editable by editing it in the clone source. Here's an example I made in Inkscape using the same technique.

There is a script for this: ofn-gradient-along-path. It works on  a path but you can obtain a path from the selection.*
Starting with the selection:

You use Select > To path to obtain a path (here I made the path visible), and remove the selection (otherwise you get only one half the gradient):

You then right click the path in the path list and click Decorate > Gradient along path:

Set at least the width. The gradient used is the active gradient, here, something like this:

And run the script:

The download page has installation instructions at the bottom, and the ZIP contains a small HTML doc.

I installed the script properly, as far as I know, and even restarted GIMP afterwards, but there is no menu in which the script shows up.
This includes the Paths tab, where I right-click the selection. There is nothing there.
What am I doing wrong?

If installed properly you can find it in Help > Procedure browser and Help > Plug-in browser. You can also execute by entering / that opens a search window, and then entering Gradient. Otherwise what is your OS?
